# Showing that $EF = 0$ and $EF^t = I_4$ without using determinants but images and kernels

Tags: linear-algebra

We have two $4\times 4$ matrices, $E$ and $F$. And $EF = 0$, and $EF^t = I_4$, where $F^t$ denotes the transpose of $t$ and $I_4$ the identity matrix in $M_4(\mathbb{R})$.

By using determinants, you're able to prove this statement false since the determinant of $EF$ and $EF^t$ are the same, yet the determinants of the corresponding $0$ and identity matrix in $\mathbb{R}^4$ are different. However, how would you go about approaching this in terms of images and kernels?

Thanks!

Edited for clarity--

Comment: Er...what are you talking about, anyway? What matrices/operators are $\,E,F\,$ ? Over what field/ring/whatever are they defined? What's $\,I\,$ and what's $\,I^4\,$ ? Is it raining in Ulan Bator now?...

Comment: haha good point. I edited the question--

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 2):

This is not really talking about images nor kernels, but :
$0 = 0E^tF^t = EFE^tF^t = (EF^tE^t)^tF^t = (E^t)^tF^t = EF^t = I_4$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

So we have two matrices (operators) $\,E\,,\,F\,$ of order $\,4\times 4\,$ over the reals, and we can think of them as operators (matrices).

Hints: The following are facts you should check you understand and can prove that follows from the basics and/or from the given data:

$$1)\;\;\;x\in\ker(EF)\iff E(Fx)=0\iff Fx\in\ker E,\;\text{and from here we get that}$$
$$\; EF=0\implies \text{Im}\,F\le\ker E$$

$$2)\;\;\;\text{row rank of $\,F\,=$ column rank of $\,F\,=\,$ row rank of $\,F^t\,$ }$$

$$3)\;\;\;\dim\text{Im}\,F=\text{ column rank}\ldots etc.$$